# Web API - IgnoreRoute returns strange 404 page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-web-api2

I have added the following routes:

```
    // Ignore the alternate path to the home page
    routes.IgnoreRoute("Home/Index");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("Home");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new {  id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Accessing: http://localhost:60832/home
(Please note HOME is a known controller, but ignored in routing as shown above)

[image: 404 Page - Known Controller]

Accessing: http://localhost:60832/testme
I get this 404 page:
[image]

Why are they so different?
Why isn't the same 404 page returned?

Please note this is happening both on WebAPI and MVC Web Application projects, with the same routes defined.

Comment: It appears the `IgnoreRoute` makes that configuration modification at the IIS level while the others are routed to ASP.NET MVC via IIS but then fail inside the MVC router.

Comment: Do you want to execute a controller from browser without routing framework, is it possible?

Comment: I just wanted to `close` the `home` `home/index`, but then got this bizarre behavior. @MichaelPerrenoud - my guess was the same like yours, one is treated as a static file, the other as an .NET, but why?

Comment: @Dementic because that's how they implemented it? Likely for performance, but I didn't build the code so I don't know why really. However, this can be resolved by configuration IIS to point to a specific 404 page that is then a good MVC route.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud - So i guess the `ignoreRoute` dosent really ignore the route, but processes it and throws a 404 since its not `allowed`?

Comment: "I just wanted to close the home home/index", you have already done that,   that is why 404, resource not found.

Comment: @AnilKumar - yes, i did, but i would have felt more comfortable if it was treated the same way and trying to understand the logic behind the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because for `/home` you have handled the exception by ignoring it and that is why you are getting proper 404.

For wrong c`ontroller/action (testme/indexa)` it is looking it in routing table and throwing the unhandled exception that I have not found any resource (URI) by this name.

For preventing routing to handle requests for a URL pattern you can use [StopRoutingHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.stoproutinghandler.stoproutinghandler.aspx)

```
 routes.Add(new Route("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}", new StopRoutingHandler()));
```

Comment: just to make things clear if someone lands here.
There is no `exception` as Anil is describing.
.NET is processing the route, see's it should ignore it and throws a 404.
The other page is parsed as a static page, since there is no route at all defined for it and IIS returns the 404.

Comment: just not to keep this question unanswered, i award you the points.